# How to adjust Screen brightness of Acer Aspire 573z?

Tags: screen, brightness, acer, aspire

I have tried many thing given on internet and also on Ubuntu but nothing works.

Comment: Okay - could you tell us these things? And we prefer correct English here.

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

1. Add `acpi_osi=Linux` and `acpi_backlight=vendor` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` in `/etc/default/grub`.
2. `sudo update-grub2`
3. Reboot.

Comment: This worked for me on an Aspire 7315 in CentOS 7 (apart from the `update-grub2` command, which I worked around with https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336508/38647)